# ColdFusion/mySQL - quotation marks and apostrophes

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery

I'm having an issue when inserting data into a mySQL database using a ColdFusion application. I've tried REPLACE and PRESERVESINGLEQUOTES and a few other things, but I'm lost at this point.

It's basically wherever I have a textbox or textfield in a form - users aren't allowed to use quotation marks in the fields (an error gets sent back - You have an error in your SQL syntax;) and when an apostrophe is used it gets doubled (a word like Mark's gets turned into Mark''s)

Any help would be appreciated. My head is about to burst.

---

**SOLUTION: cfqueryparam**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using `cfqueryparam` Something like this will work

```
<cfset userEnteredData = "I'm using apostrophes">

<cfquery>
INSERT INTO data (userText)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#userEnteredData#">)
</cfquery>
```

**EDIT**

Do this for three reasons:

1. This creates a "[bind variable](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)", which (among other things) protects against SQL Injection attacks.
2. `CFQUERYPARAM` automatically escapes quotes and apostrophes.
3. If you're passing a list of variables, it will correctly escape the list based on the cfsqltype if you use the `list` attribute.

Comment: Reason 4 - can speed up execution time of the query if said query is frequently run.

Comment: Thanks much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

Always use [`cfqueryparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) ... It'll solve your issue and make your application more secure.

Comment: Upvoted because it was submitted two minutes before Matt's answer.